# How to get input data from html to nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning node, express and I want get input from html form, something like a signup form to js so that I can get it in mongoDB.

The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'uname')
    at exports.chat_create (E:\JS_stuff\controllers\chat.controller.js:20:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (E:\JS_stuff\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

What I want to do is get the input from field uname and umail to js so it can insert into mongodb.

This works if I don't try to take input and just add value, something like `name : 'name'`.
Here is the code:

controller.js

```
const { default: mongoose } = require('mongoose');
const request = require('request');
const Chats = require('../models/chat.model');

exports.test = function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello, this is a test controller!');
};

exports.chat_create = function(req, res, next) {
    var uname = req.body.uname;
    var umail = req?.body?.umail;
    let ch = new Chats({
        name: uname,
        mail: umail
    });

    ch.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        res.send('Chat added.');
    })
};
```

model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let ChatSchema = new Schema({
    name : {type: String, required: true},
    mail: {type: String},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Chats', ChatSchema);
```

route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const chat_controller = require('../controllers/chat.controller');

router.get('/test', chat_controller.test);
router.get('/create', chat_controller.chat_create);
router.get('/read/:id', chat_controller.read_chat);
router.get('/:id/update', chat_controller.update_chat);
router.get('/delete/:id', chat_controller.delete_chat);

module.exports = router;
```

```
app.js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var JSDOM = jsdom.JSDOM;
// const request = require('request');
// import route
const chat = require('./routes/chat.route');

// initialize app
const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs")
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs').__express);
app.use('/chat', chat);

// set up mongoose connection
let db_url = 'the url';
let mongoDB = process.env.MONGODB_URI || db_url;
mongoose.connect(mongoDB);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
let db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error: '));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app._router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

// port
let port  = 1234;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("Server is running on port " + port);
});

app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
    res.render("form");
});
```

form.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="form.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="forms">
            <div class="form signup">
                <span class="title">Register</span>
                    <form action="/chat/create" method="POST">   
                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" id="uname" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                        <i class="uil uil-user"></i>
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-field">
                        <input type="text" id="umail" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                        <i class="uil uil-envelope icon"></i>
                    </div>
                
                    <a href="/chat/create">
                        <div class="input-field button">
                            <input type="submit" value="Register">
                        </div>
                    </a>        
              </form>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [The  placeholder attribute is not a substitute for the label element](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201204/the_html5_placeholder_attribute_is_not_a_substitute_for_the_label_element/)

Comment: in route.js change `route.get('/create'...)` to `route.post('/create'..)` because this route is handling post request of the form not a get request